# Sumif and countif criteria isn't working in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, countif, inequality

I am writing an excel vba code for expected shortfall evaluation.

My sumif and countif functions return value 0 if I put in criteria ' "<" & Var ' (value at risk - percentile of array at 2,5%), if I reverse that criteria (">") these functions sum/count all values in range.

I can't find the mistake, can anyone help?
Here is a part of the code:

```
Dim RiskHorizon As Integer
RiskHorizon = InputBox("Set the Risk Horizon!", "Risk Horizon", 10)
Dim SigLev As Double
SigLev = InputBox("Set the Significance Level!", "Significance Level", 0.025)
Dim CountDates As Integer
CountDates = Application.CountIf(Sheets("ExpSh").Columns("A"), "<>" & "") - 1
Dim ReturnRange As Range
Set ReturnRange = Sheets("ExpSh").Range("C2:C" & CountDates - RiskHorizon + 1)
Dim Var As Double
Dim ES As Double
Dim Sums As Double
Dim Counts As Double
Var = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(ReturnRange, SigLev)
Sums = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ReturnRange, "<" & Var)
Counts = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ReturnRange, "<" & Var)
ES = Sums / Counts
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Sums = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ReturnRange, ""<"" & Var)
Counts = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ReturnRange, ""<"" & Var)
```

Comment: Still the same result. :(